# Trouble with adding numbers in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to add the price of some books when each one checked but I have a problem. 
It just adds a string. For example, when I select a book(10$), the price becomes 10 and when I select another book(20$) it becomes 1020, and so on...

My code :
 For book one :

```
<input 
  name="bookList" 
  type="checkbox" 
  id="bookList_1" 
  onChange="
    if (document.getElementById('bookList_1').checked) {
    document.getElementById('priceDes').innerHTML='  total:  ';
    document.getElementById('price').innerHTML+=10;
    }
  " 
  value="book1"
>
```

For book two :

```
<input 
  name="bookList" 
  type="checkbox" 
  id="bookList_2" 
  onChange="
    if (document.getElementById('bookList_2').checked) {
      document.getElementById('priceDes').innerHTML='  total:  ';
      document.getElementById('price').innerHTML+=20;
    }
  " 
  value="book1"
>
```

And the price and priceDes are `<p>` tags ...
Thanks for your solutions ;)

Comment: What'd you expect when you "add" to strings?  Convert them to numbers first.

Comment: Try `document.getElementById('price').innerHTML=parseInt(document.getElementById('price').innerHTML)+10;`

Comment: @tewathia I was writing exact code as answer, but you've written it first. Please post it as answer.

Comment: That's none of my doing though, let me just point out.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're concatenating strings, instead of adding numbers. '10'+'20' gives '1020' and not 30.

Try:
`document.getElementById('price').innerHTML=parseInt(document.getElementById('pr‌​ice').innerHTML)+10;`

Be careful with this though, it would only work if your `p` tags have only the numbers inside their HTML. `parseInt('10$')` gives `10` but `parseInt('$10')` gives `NaN`. You can experiment with [number-type input](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_number) tags.

Comment: thank U very much :) that's work ! ... also your last hint ... I add 0 too my p tag as default ...

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById('price').innerHTML=Number(document.getElementById('price').innerHTML)+20;`

Answer (score -1):

InnerHTML is a string. The + operator is also the String concatenate operator in JavaScript. So, "cast" the values first.

Easy way to "cast" numerical strings in JavaScript: multiply by 1:

```
var rv = 1*a.innerHTML + 1*b.innerHTML;
```

Or, use the Number constructor:

```
var rv = Number(a.innerHTML) + Number(b.innerHTML);
```